# How to fix function that is returning unexpected results in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range **Room_ResultsGUI** and want to create simple function that will return value. But my function return nothing...not error just blank value, not sure why.

**TasGUID** is string with bracket here is example {6086FA55-54E5-4474-8599-2BB696170C73}
I am checking row and column reference, from first row and column and then just returning cells with row and column.
Not sure how to solve it, and why it does not work?

```
Function S(TasGUID As Variant) As Variant

    On Error GoTo blad:
    Dim bladTekst As String
    Dim category As String
    Dim zakres As Range

    category = "Total Room Air Flow Rate [l/s]"
    zakres = Range("Room_ResultsGUI")

    Dim kolumna As Long, wiersz As Long
    bladTekst = "No Data"

    kolumna = WorksheetFunction.Match(category, zakres.Rows(1), 0)
    wiersz = WorksheetFunction.Match(TasGUID, zakres.Columns(1), 0)
    S = zakres.Cells(wiersz, kolumna)

    Exit Function
blad:
    S = bladTekst
End Function
```

My current code:

```
Function S(TasGUID As Variant) As Variant

    Dim category As String
    Dim zakres As Range
    Dim kolumna As Long, wiersz As Long

    category = "Total Room Air Flow Rate [l/s]"
    kolumna = WorksheetFunction.Match(category, Range("Room_ResultsGUI").Rows(1), 0)
    wiersz = WorksheetFunction.Match(TasGUID, Range("Room_ResultsGUI").Columns(1), 0)
    S = zakres.Cells(wiersz, kolumna)

End Function
```

Comment: `not error just blank vlaue not sure why` Remove the line `On Error GoTo blad:` and you will know why :)

Comment: Hint: Something wrong with the line `zakres = Range("Room_ResultsGUI")`? ;)

Comment: no I have #VALUE! ..

Comment: Another Hint: How is `zakres` declared as?

Comment: I tried many options aslo as zakres = "Room_ResultsGUI" but it does not solve it

Comment: That second attempt was still using **zakres** in `S = zakres.Cells(wiersz, kolumna)` but you had got rid of it everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Set** a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

```
SET zakres = Range("Room_ResultsGUI")
```

I'm not so sure why it is important to set it anyway. Using it like,

```
Function S(TasGUID As Variant) As Variant

    On Error GoTo blad:
    Dim category As String
    Dim kolumna As Long, wiersz As Long

    category = "Total Room Air Flow Rate [l/s]"
    S = "No Data"

    kolumna = WorksheetFunction.Match(category, Range("Room_ResultsGUI").Rows(1), 0)
    wiersz = WorksheetFunction.Match(TasGUID, Range("Room_ResultsGUI").Columns(1), 0)
    S = Range("Room_ResultsGUI").Cells(wiersz, kolumna)

    Exit Function
blad:
    S = Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Function
```

... would be sufficient. I've also removed your generic "No data" in favour of an actual error number and description.

Comment: I corrected code to your advice and still it same error, hmm not sure why

Comment: is **Room_ResultsGUI** on the same worksheet? If not, what worksheet is it on?

Comment: I spent already 2 hr on that task testing with many different options have no clue where is the problem

Comment: See my full modifications above. If you are recieiving `1004 - Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class
` then one or both of the match functions are not returning a value. fwiw, this works for me anywhere in the workbook with Room_ResultsGUI defined as a named range with Workbook scope.

Comment: thanks Jeeped...your code is working! thanks a lot, Ps. where/how you can see error number?

Comment: Minimalism is not a bad coding philosophy. I mean, you had already created a named range to isolate your data block. It seems redundant to declare and assign a range object variable to the same thing just to make the range reference 6 characters long instead of 24.

Comment: If you try to look for a value that is not in column 1 the function will return that error code.